# VScode configuration for MPI arguments

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, mpi

I am trying to set up my VScode debugger on Linux for C++ programs using mpi.
While compilation and running works fine, I struggle to make the debugger add the command line arguments in the case of mpi code. The `argv` array just holds garbage. Also, the debugger does not launch the number of processes specified with the `-np` option in the launch.json file.
Everything works fine if I just run the code manually using `mpirun -np 2 code.exe arg1 arg2...`

Any help is appreciated.

Here are my .vscode files:

**tasks.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "mpicxx build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/mpicxx",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "MPI Build and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [
          "-np",  // should govern number of processes launched
          "1",    // by mpi
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "0",    // these arguments are additional arguments
          "0.01", // used by the program
          "5",    
          "10"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "preLaunchTask": "mpicxx build active file",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    }
  ]
}
```

To find the mpi header, one also needs a **c_cpp_properties.json**:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it :

First, there is a paragraph on [OpenMPI's website](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers) that describes how to build a breakpoint in all MPI processes and attach GDB to each of those processes.

With VSCode, I've added this configuration to `launch.json` :

```
,
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "program": "path/to/your/exe",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

And for example, if I run `mpirun -np 4 ./ComputeInverseSquare_x64`, with `ComputeInverseSquare` looking like something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   MPI_Init();

   int idProc, nbProc;
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &idProc);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbProc);

   int volatile j = 1;
   while(j)
      sleep(5);
  
   // compute some inverse square of something
   // ...


   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

Then, in VSCode, when hitting f5 or launch "(gdb) Attach" configurations, the `command:pickProcess` is gonna be trigger and I can search for my executables whose name are `ComputeInverseSquare` and I'll see 4 of them with different PID that I can attach to and debug.

Hope that helps.

Additional info on :

1. [how to use GDB on Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_windows-debugging-with-gdb)
2. [how to attach running processes with VSCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out soon and let you know. I never worked with attaching a debugger to a running session, so I want to try a serial case first. So the procedure is: Use mpirun from terminal with input arguments one wants to use, then attach GDB to this running session using the configuration you described?

Comment: If you have an exe `ComputeInverseSquare`, you can : build yourself a breakpoint like I explained and is explain on OpenMPI's website with a volatile variable and a while loop. Run your exe, it'll go to sleep mode. Get the PID of your exe how ever you'd like. And do `gdb -p pid` where pid is the PID of your exe.