# MPI_Put seg fault with multiple processes

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I am working on a program to learn MPI one-sided communication. In the program, each process receives a local array with N key,value pairs. The local N can vary, so each process can have a different size array. The program should sort the arrays so that process 0 get all the values that have the key 0, process 1 should get all the values that have the key 1, and so on all the way to process P-1.

My strategy is to first have each process run through their local arrays and count how many values they own for each process in a local array called local_counts. Then I use an MPI_Allreduce to find the global counts in the array global_counts. Then I use an MPI_Exscan to find the prefix sums so that I know which indices of the array each process should place a value in another process’ RMA window.

I create the window_buffer with the appropriate size, create an RMA window, use MPI_fence to begin and end an epoch, and inside the epoch I go through the local array and place value i in the correct index of the correct process’ RMA window.

When I test it with 1 process, this works fine. However, it does not seem to be working with multiple processes, which kinda defeats the point. What am I doing wrong here that it doesn’t work for more than 1 process? I would post the exact output but I’m using an auto-grader that gives extremely limited feedback. It only tells me that I’ve in correctly sorted the values, which could mean a segfault or wrong answers. I know it does work for 1 process though. Thanks!

My program, sort.cpp:

---

```
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

#include "helper.h"
#include "sort.h"

void my_sort(int N, item *myItems, int *nOut, item **myResult)
{
    int rank, nprocs;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int local_counts[nprocs] = {0};
    int global_counts[nprocs] = {0};
    int prefix_global_sum[nprocs] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int key = myItems[i].key;
        local_counts[key]++;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Initial array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d ", myItems[i].value);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");

    MPI_Allreduce(local_counts, global_counts, nprocs, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Exscan(local_counts, prefix_global_sum, nprocs, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nprocs; i++)
        {
            prefix_global_sum[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    *nOut = global_counts[rank]; 
    item *window_buffer[*nOut] = {0};
    MPI_Win window;
    *myResult = (item *)malloc(*nOut * sizeof(item));
    MPI_Win_create((*myResult), (MPI_Aint)*nOut * sizeof(item), sizeof(item), MPI_INFO_NULL,    MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);

    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        val* value = &myItems[i].value;
        int target_rank = myItems[i].key;
        int target_offset = prefix_global_sum[target_rank];
        MPI_Put(value, sizeof(item), MPI_BYTE, target_rank, target_offset, sizeof(item), MPI_BYTE, window);
        prefix_global_sum[target_rank] += 1;
    }

    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

    MPI_Win_free(&window);
}
```

sort.h:

---

```
#ifndef SORT_H
#define SORT_H

#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream> // for debugging, if you like
#include <mpi.h>
#include "helper.h"

void my_sort(int N, item *myItems, int *nOut, item **myResult);

#endif
```

Comment: Maybe I should sort the local values into local arrays for P0, P1, etc. and *then* do the MPI_Put with an entire array, instead of doing an MPI_Put one value at a time? Would that make a difference?

Comment: Recommendations: Ask the the more useful question you intended to ask and not *Could someone look at my code and steer me in the right direction?* The answer to that is almost certainly an utterly unhelpful "Yes." You should also add the output of any debugger runs you've performed to help narrow down the source of the problem (and show you've taken the debugging seriously).

Comment: Ah. Your comment suggests you've fallen into the common trap of treating Stack Overflow like a forum. It's not a forum. This is a Q&A site. You ask a question. We provide concrete answers to that question. If there are no concrete answers to be had, you're going to have a substandard user experience. If you want a more iterative process, like a discussion about your code, Stack Overflow is not the place. If you wish to proceed, give [mre] and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) a read and revisit the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I’ve updated the question accordingly. @user4581301

Comment: Also, I don’t have many debugging tools at my disposal, just an auto-grader that basically says pass/fail and a very basic “test” program. I have been trying to debug on my own though. I feel like I may be misunderstanding something with how MPI_Put works, or with my logic. @user4581301

Comment: I can't help much on that front. I haven't used MPI in a long time. But Autograders and judges suck. They never give you the right information to solve problems. You need to write your own test jig and test cases so you can look for failures yourself. Take advantage of anally retentive compiler warnings (`-Wall` and `-Wextra` at a minimum in GCC-compatible toolchains) to get the most out of the compiler diagnostics and turn on whatever sanitizers you have available (`-fsanitize=address,undefined` most likely. I don't think the `thread` sanitizer will work with MPI).

Comment: @coffeeanddonuts you can create a breakpoint in your program and attach gdb to your processes, here for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845901/vscode-configuration-for-mpi-arguments

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]. meanwhile add some code to ensure there is no overflow when populating local_counts

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your logic. You update `prefix_global_sum[target_rank]` after you put data on `target_rank`. But what if another process puts data on that same rank? Then your information is no longer correct.

The way to fix this is to let each process maintain its own `prefix_global_sum` value, and when you want to put data on that process, you first have to query that value from that target rank.